# How to put lookup array column dynamically in match formula

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am trying to do a MATCH and dynamically taking the column from cell D1, I am concatenating the value from D1 cell as follows

```
=MATCH(A6,"Sheet1!"&D1&":"&D1,0)
```

D1 contains a formula which returns the column, here, assume D1 contains "Y", so, the above formula should look like this

```
=MATCH(A6,Sheet1!Y:Y,0)
```

but instead I am getting a #VALUE error

Is there a way to do a MATCH without manually putting the column and using a column value from some other cell?

Comment: Try using `Indirect(D1)&":"&Indirect(D1)`

Comment: Try: `=MATCH(A6,INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&D1&":"&D1),0)`. But how did you end up with a `Y` in `D1`?